# ionic 2 calendar cssClass not working

Tags: calendar, ionic3

I'm using https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar to generate a calendar in ionic. I can't make color changes to dates using dateconfig's cssClass.

Below is the code i'm using

` daysConfig() {

```
let _daysConfig = [
  {
    date:new Date(2018,0,1),
    subTitle:'New Year\'s',
    marked:false,
    cssClass: 'my-cal'
  },
  {
    date:new Date(2017,1,14),
    subTitle:'Valentine\'s',
    disable:true
  },
  {
    date:new Date(2017,3,1),
    subTitle:'April Fools',
    marked:true
  },
  {
    date:new Date(2017,3,7),
    subTitle:'World Health',
    marked:true
  },
  {
    date:new Date(2017,4,31),
    subTitle:'No-Smoking',
    marked:true
  },
  {
    date:new Date(2017,5,1),
    subTitle:'Children\'s',
    marked:true
  }
];

_daysConfig.push(...this.days);

this.calendarCtrl.openCalendar({
  from: new Date(2017,0,1),
  to  : new Date(2018,11.1),
  daysConfig:_daysConfig
})
  .then( (res:any) => { console.log(res) })
  .catch( () => {} )
```

}`

css Class 
`.my-cal {
  color: yellow
}`

Comment: do you need to change colour of selected date? If so, you can use ion-calendar-month .primary .days .on-selected class to override background color property.

Comment: yes but i want to add custom colors by not selecting like events i want to show on different colors

Comment: did anyone get solution

Answer (score 0):

**After a long RnD of almost 5 hour could solve this issue.**

Please find the below solution in ionic

Define the below class in global.scss

```
.my-cal {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

and remember not to define this class anywhere else.

*now use this in you days config as below:*

```
let _daysConfig: DayConfig[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      _daysConfig.push({
        date: new Date(2020, 4, i + 1),
        marked: false,
        subTitle: `$${i + 1}`,
        cssClass: 'my-cal'
      })
    }
```

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem, and I solved it by adding the follow style in the .scss file:

```
button.days-btn.my-cal {
    p, small {
        color: yellow;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The cssClass is only added to the button that the `<p>` element containing the text is in.

So to properly change the color, you'll have to reference the `<p>` element first and assign the color to that.

Example

.ts

`cssClass: 'my-cal'`

.scss

```
.my-cal {

 p {

   color: green;

 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions would be to add this code to your global scss/css style

```
ion-calendar { .my-cal{ background-color: #6E6B6B !important; p{ color: white !important; } }}
```

Later add "my-cal" class to wanted day.

Comment: i think you did not add this code in global.scss...this is working fine in ionic 4 project.
in ts file
this.test.push({
                          date: new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), this.date.getDate()),
                          //marked: true,
                          //title: i+[innerHTML]="<sup>0</sup>",
                          subTitle: 'p',
                          cssClass: 'my-cal'
                        }) 
                    }